# What is name of this part in the picture?

Tags: part-identification, car

Could you guys please tell me the name of the part in red square in English?
[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would refer to it as a CV (constant velocity) joint spider.

Comment: Do you want to add an equivalent picture for the OP?  Might help illustrate that, yes, this is the right thing: e.g., http://web.tradekorea.com/upload_file2/product/380/P00326380/oimg_GC03113655_CA03113662.jpg